# how to make if else condition check

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I am trying to do is in below code is when I check the checkbox1, variants is shown and on uncheck it hides and when I check checkbox2 it shows the colour tab and toggles red green blue. This functionality work fine for me .

But what I try to achieve is when i click on both check boxes then it shows this
image link here

My expected result

[image]

and when I uncheck the checkbox then it shows this

[image]

I try to check style if() else() condition  but it does not work.

```js
function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container-2 {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="" onclick="addDay(this)" />2
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>


<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">

    <br>
    <!-- Nav pills -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#homemade">variant</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="homemade" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD NEW</button>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>


  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
    <br>
    <!-- Nav pills -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Colors</a>
      </li>


    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Red</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Blue</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
            <h3>Red</h3>

          </div>
          <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Green</h3>

          </div>
          <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Blue</h3>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">test</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you WANT to see and what you ARE seeing. In chrome it seems that I am seeing what you posted as expected result

Comment: Please make images as links. Otherwise, it is difficult to perceive the question!

Comment: @s.kuznetsov ***I*** made the images show when I edited since I want them inline so I can scroll up and down. You can just right click and open in new tab if you want them elsewhere

Comment: "*but it does not work*" - please elaborate.  Showing/Hiding of the two panels works fine - but the final result isn't 100% what your screenshot shows - that's nothing to do with the hide/show that's your html layout/css.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov do you mean images as *only* links?  Not as inline images?  Or both?    Are you referring to the original, mplungjan's edit or my edit?

Comment: The question should be as compact and convenient as possible for visual perception. But when you specify several images, it is not visually convenient.

Comment: It's *far less* convenient to have to click an image to see it...  I'll agree they're somewhat oversized

Comment: Back to the question:  you have multiple options, an "if-else" would not be suitable here.  I would say the code you do have is correct for the multiple options, but you may need to split your tab header/tab body and show both to get the layout you need.  In which case you'll need to change to a class or other selector as IDs must be unique.

Comment: I am trying to make when i click on checkbox 1  then variants tab and add new button show its work fine but when i click on  checkbox2 then colours tab show and red green and blue nav tab is show on the place of add new button and add new button come down and again when i unclick the checkbox2 the add new button show in original position

Comment: when click checkbox 1 and 2 both then show https://ibb.co/VV3kHVg this type and when click checkbox 1 then show this type https://ibb.co/ZxDdNbG

Comment: @freedomn-m what ur edited in my code i want this type https://ibb.co/VV3kHVg hope u understand what i m trying to do

Comment: Right, that's your HTML/CSS layout, the js is fine

Comment: @freedomn-m  can u help me out this

Comment: @freedomn-m  yes i try to achive when click on both checkbox 1 and 2 then its show this type https://ibb.co/VV3kHVg and when checkbox1 click then its https://ibb.co/ZxDdNbG

Comment: yes its HTML/CSS/bootstrap layout @freedomn-m

Comment: @mplungjan i want to try when i click on checkbox 1 then variants tab and add new button show its work fine but when i click on checkbox2 then colours tab show and red green and blue nav tab is show on the place of add new button and add new button come down and again when i unclick the checkbox2 the add new button show in original position

Comment: hope u understand my concern what i m trying to achive